# IOS: Universal way to get type of class

Tags: ios, class

Is there a universal way to get the type of class of an object such as:

```
NSString *classType = [Class kind];
```

rather than iterating through them like:

```
if ([object isKindOfClass: [NSNull Class]]) {
//it is null
}
else if ([object isKindOfClass: [NSObject Class]]) {
//it is an object
}
```

//and so forth

Comment: try classforCode method

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString * NSStringFromClass(Class aClass);
```

Comment: dumb question.  how would you call this?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([NSString class])); will output "NSString" into console

Comment: Let's say you have NSNumber *num=@1;  Will this tell me if num is an nsnumber? NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([num class]));  I can't get it to.

Comment: That's because `NSNumber` is actually a [class cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html) - that is, while you may initialize an `NSNumber`, you may get back a private subclass like `__NSCFNumber`. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

While it is common to use NSStringFromClass(anObj), you should also know about Swift 3's type(of:) function.

```
import Foundation
class Foo:NSObject {}
let bar = Foo()
let barType = type(of:bar)
print("\(barType)")
```

Looks like this in playgrounds:

[image]